# Is there any stable version of Skype for Linux?

Tags: skype

I have Skype 5.4.0.1 Beta, but as I see it's not stable, it has quite a lot of bugs. I'm working on remote and I need stable Skype, is there any solution?

Comment: Best thing to do: don't use it and use something else. discord works too and is a lot better.

Comment: @Rinzwind but I need to comnunicate with other skype users

Comment: is it possible to call to skype users from discord?

Comment: I too am very dissatisfied with Skype after it was bought by Microsoft. From alternatives, jitsi meet looks promising to me - it only requires a web browser and works on Ubuntu/Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2017, there is only **Beta release of Skype for Linux 64 bit**

The point to be noted is that apart from the **Bright screen promise on the Skype website** they have made zero efforts to release a stable version. It has been in Beta for ages.

**============= Update ================**

After prolonged searches and I have somehow landed on [this skype.com](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu32) page where you can get the 32 Bit official Skype (Although V 4.3 it works great)

[skype 32 bit](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu32)

I have tried this and works great, even the voice calls ...!!
[image: Skype 4.3 32 bit logged in screen On LXLE x86 (32 bit)]

Offical 64-bit Skype can be found [here on skype.com](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=weblinux-deb)

I guess they are updating the site now...

Comment: Where did you get this information? Since version 4.3, Skype beta has been available, but since approx version 5.3 it's been called stable (although the web site incorrectly still calls it beta). Now they're recently released a new "preview" version of skype, but you can't get that from the normal download page.

Comment: @heynnema updated the answer while I actually meant beta, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Your answer is still technically incorrect. Nothing has changed in Sept 2017... other than the new "preview" version (see my answer). Although the web site incorrectly calls it beta, they've renamed it and called it "stable". 4.3 no longer works as you can't sign in.

Comment: @heynnema attached screenshot of skype 4.3 working on my LXLE 32 bit linux machine

Comment: Amazing! I thought they had disabled all 4.3 logins! Go Microsoft! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft owns Skype now, and they say you must have the latest version for it to work properly, as of July 2017, although some people claim older versions are still working.

They offer the .deb for Debian based Linux distros, such as Ubuntu, and the .rpm version for Red Hat based distros.

You can get the latest stable packaes here:

[Official Download Page for "Skype for Linux"](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)

Comment: @karel they've renamed the **beta** to **stable**, but forgotten to update the web page... just like they've forgotten to release ANY version after 4.3 that's worth using. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since Microsoft has taken over Skype, and dumped the 4.3 version which worked fine, nothing has been the same. As long as you're using the latest download, which I believe that you are, you'll have to live with the bugs.

They do have new "preview" version of Skype... which I'm sure is even less stable... see https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64-preview.deb